# How to make first letter of paragraph bigger?

Tags: xetex, paragraphs, lettrine

[image]

How can I attain the structure as shown in image?

Comment: The type of lettering you're interested in is generally called "dropped capitals" in English. Are you familiar with the [lettrine](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) package?